# Mongodb return array of strings instead array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I use this code to query tokens from users in mongo db (nodejs with mongoose):

```
UserMdl.find().exists('token').select('token').exec(function onUsersFound(err, userMdls) {
  console.log(userMdls);
});
```

So I'm getting:

```
[ { 
  _id: 5447e36a60e5d15678de486c,
  token: '34f83483cc0ed82e17c162d'
}, ... ]
```

Is there any way to get an array of strings:

```
[ '34f83483cc0ed82e17c162d', ... ]
```

Right now what I'm doing is post-processing the response. I'm asking this question because I think that maybe there is a faster way to do it in mongoose/mongodb query.

**EDIT**

Post-processing I'm doing right now:

```
var results = [];
userMdls.forEach(function (userMdl) {
  results.push(userMdl.token);
});
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to saintedlama response, I've done some testing and those are the results:

Data: 14.976 documents
Tests: 100
Results:

`.find().exists('token').exec(..)`: 1236.33 ms
 `.aggregate({..})`: 136.07 ms

Test code:

```
  var start,
    end,
    time,
    firstTimes = [],
    secondTimes = [],
    test = 0,
    firstFinal,
    secondFinal,
    i,
    Q = require('q'),
    UserMdl = require('models/user'),
    u,
    tokens = [];


  function promiseWhile(condition, body) {
    var done = Q.defer();

    function repeatTest() {
      start = new Date().getTime();

      UserMdl.find().exists('token').exec(function onUserMdlFound(err, users) {
        for (u = 0; u < users.length; u += 1) {
          tokens.push(users[u].token);
        }

        end = new Date().getTime();
        time = end - start;
        firstTimes.push(time);
        start = new Date().getTime();
        tokens = [];

        UserMdl.aggregate({
          $match: {
            token: {
              $exists: true
            }
          }
        }, {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            token: 1
          }
        }, function onUserMdlFoundAggregate(err, users) {
          for (u = 0; u < users.length; u += 1) {
            tokens.push(users[u].token);
          }

          end = new Date().getTime();
          time = end - start;
          secondTimes.push(time);
          tokens = [];

          if (condition()) {
            Q.when(body(), repeatTest, done.reject);
          } else {
            return done.resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    }

    Q.nextTick(repeatTest);

    return done.promise;
  }


  function printResult() {
    firstFinal = 0;
    secondFinal = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < firstTimes.length; i += 1) {
      firstFinal += firstTimes[i];
      secondFinal += secondTimes[i];
    }
    console.log("First mean: " + firstFinal / i + " - Second mean: " + secondFinal / i);
  }

  test = 1;
  promiseWhile(function condition() {
    return test <= 300;
  }, function body() {
    console.log("running test: " + test);
    test++;
    return Q.delay(0); // arbitrary async

  }).then(function () {
    console.log("Finish testing");
    printResult();

  }).done();
```

Comment: The mongodb aggregation framework has quite good performance but in your performance tests the mongoose query UserMdl.find() returns full mongoose documents. To speed up "normal" mongoose queries where you don't need the full mongoose document you can use UserMdl.find().lean() to prevent mongoose to construct full documents. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean for more detail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a way to select only tokens that require less processing using the mongodb [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

```
UserMdl.aggregate(
  { $match: { token : { $exists : true }}},
  { $project: { _id: 0, token: 1 }},
  function onUsersFound(err, tokens) {
    console.log(tokens);
  });
);
```

This constructs an aggregation pipeline that first matches all documents that have a token field and then selects the token field and suppresses _id selection by using `_id : 0` in the `$project` pipeline step.

The post processing step would look like this:

```
function postProcess(tokenObjects) {
  if (!tokenObjects) {
    return [];
  }

  return tokenObjects.map(function(tokenObject) { return tokenObject.token; });  
}
```

See also [the mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) for more detail on the aggregation function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special. Just change one thing in your code:

*Your code*

```
UserMdl.find().exists('token').select('token').exec(function onUsersFound(err, userMdls) {
    console.log(userMdls);    // (*) Change this to...
});
```

*Change*

```
UserMdl.find().exec((err, users) => {
    console.log(users.map(user => user.token));    // ...(*) to this
});
```

No need to use `select` & `exists` functions

---

**EDIT**

The best option is Mongoose [distinct](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.distinct) function:

```
const tokens = await UserMdl.distinct('token');
```

If you want condition then:

```
const tokens = await UserMdl.find(/* condition */).distinct('token');
```

Thats it

Comment: The downside of this approach is that Mongo first returns everything to the client, and the client does the logic. Whereas aggregation pipeline pushes the work to Mongo.

Comment: Absolutely. But distinct is much simpler & faster